# Excel Lookup table, text of lookup value gives error

Tags: excel

I am currently trying to fix a very strange error with a LOOKUP function where the text in the lookup value will sometimes give an #N/A.

The function works perfectly apart from when certain text is used.

If i use the word "Solid" (a random word i put in), the lookup works and the function successfully calculates as expected.

If i change the word "Solid" to "Basic" (the actual descriptor i need to use) the formula does not work...

I HAVE NOW ATTACHED AN EXAMPLE SHEET:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzlcF4qt3Y8XQmVzSEMyMmwyNkE

Any greatly appreciated with this very weird error.

Comment: How do you expect us to help when you don't post any context?  Post the formula and perhaps an example spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this using `vlookup`. While selecting table array, selection done for whole two columns.Means you must point your mouse over F & G column names. Please refer screen-shot[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the effort! There is also another workaround where if i change the order of lookup table then i no longer get the error. Still very annoying though!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using MATCH instead of LOOKUP because LOOKUP threw me the same #N/A error you are talking about.

Here is an example which shows the row number where the match has been found:

```
=MATCH(cell_that_we_are_looking_for, cell_range:where_we_look_for_the_earlier_cell, 0)
=MATCH(A2, C$2:C$981, 0)
```